# Undefined reference to SDL_init, build log unclear

Tags: sdl

I have just setup SDL on CodeBlocks, and I am getting a build error:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in SDL learning (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -L..\deps\lib -o "bin\Debug\SDL learning.exe" obj\Debug\main.o   -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `SDL_main':
C:/Users/73638G75MA/Documents/prive/programeren/C++ projects/SDL learning/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

The build log doesn't really tell me anything, maybe some of you guys know a solution.

In case you need my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)!=0){
        cout << "Could not initiate SDL" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I got my include and lib files in folder named `deps`.

Also, it does recognize the SDL.h file and its commands, because when I type `#include <S` it suggests SDL.h. It also autocompletes the SDL commands.

Comment: Do you use library files from `x86_64...` directory? Try ones from `i686...` one.

Comment: Ok. I don't see any obvious errors here. Another idea: You can try to download MinGW-w64 or usual MinGW and use it instead of MinGW that comes with `CodeBlocks`.

Comment: Is there any difference if you switch the order of the librares being linked in , as in `-lSDL2 -lSDL2main`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I remade the deps file and now it al works. and yes nos it does, you need to put SDL2main in front of SDL2 I thought.